# When to use user-user collaborative filtering and when to use Item-Item collaborative filtering?

Tags: collaborative-filtering, recommendation-engine

I am confused when to use user-user collaborative filtering and when to use Item-Item collaborative filtering?

Please help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have more users than items in your dataset which is generally the case, it would be effective to use item-item collaborative filtering. eg: Amazon would have a huge base of customers as compared to products.

Moreover the user preferences and liking changes over time so it is difficult to tackle this problem in user-user collaborative filtering but with item generally it is seen the rating of item doesn't change much over a course of time.

Answer (score 2):

**Item-Item**:- Looks for the similar items, which user X has already rated and recommends the most similar items. Here similarity means how people treat two items in terms of ratings. If two items get same kind of ratings with the same users then they are similar.For example:-

```
        Per1    Per2    Per3
Item1    5        3        1
Ttem2    2        3        3
```

Item vector_1 =  5P1 + 3P2 + 1P3

Item vector_2 =  2P1 + 3P2 + 3P3

If we calculate the cosine similarity of two vectors:

```
Cos_sim = (5*2 + 3*3 + 1*3) / sqrt((25+9+1)*(4+9+9)
Cos_sim = 0.792
```

**User-User**:- Find similarity between users by assessing the rating pattern of two users. 
For example:-

```
        Item1    Item2    Item3    Item4
Per_x    5        2        5        2
Per_y    5        2        5        2
```

Here two users are pretty similar. This might be you and your friend.

Hope that helps !!!

Comment: In user-user approach, how do you compute similarity between two users?